# iOS BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: HARDWARE NEEDED

Tags: ios, bluetooth, submit, bluetooth-lowenergy, appstore-approval

I've made an app that connects to  BLE Device.
But my app got rejected from appstore review process.
They said I have to send hardware to submit.

How can I submit this for review? Its true that my App can't work without hardware. The hardware does connect over BLE only and is not MFi. 
It can also connect to android app.

I just want to get some clarity on what I need to do to get this app through the review process and into the App Store.

Some answers said that their app passed review process by using Video.

But, I'm not sure it works 'cause when I submitted, I included a url of video at memo field.
Actually the video was very short and not included everything.

I'm not sure What am I suppose to do.
I need your help.

------------------Received Text------------------
Hardware required

We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need the associated hardware to fully assess your app features.

At your earliest convenience, please send the necessary hardware/accessory to the address below.

NOTE: Please include your app name and app ID in the shipment; failure to provide this information can delay the review process.

Additionally, it may take several business days for us to receive the hardware once it has been delivered to Apple.

Comment: It looks pretty clear.  You need to send them your hardware at the address they have provided.

Comment: Thx for advise. I'd changed the connect logic to main without Hardware. I've  success to submit.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you tell me what did you answer them for beeing accepted please ?